# Profiling boot-to-desktop I/O usage

Tags: performance, 17.04, io

I am experiencing slow performance for several minutes after logging in to Unity desktop, with all signs pointing to I/O bottlenecks being the culprit. The desktop is nearly unusable (e.g. `gnome-settings-daemon` does not always start early, making mouse invisible and hotkeys not working, all programs take long to  until things settle down and I/O usage (as seen in `iotop`) goes down to idle levels.

In this case, I would like to gather precise data on which processes use most I/O and when. Interactive tools can give me a clue, but it would be much more helpful to find a tool that can show me total I/O activity by process from boot to usable desktop. Any pointers are welcome!